# Use the user's App Store account for multi app subscription

Tags: ios, subscription

I'm am currently implementing the multi-app subscription model for iOS apps. I have 4 apps that I want to interconnect with the same subscription. So far, the subscription works individually inside each of them and I have a backend server that receives status notifications about subscriptions.

In the Apple docs, they mention that the user should be identified by some sort of credentials between apps to know when a user has bought a subscription in one of the apps. The question here is can we use the user's app store account to identify it instead of creating custom credentials. I find it easier for users to only have their native account to work with instead of having another in-app account.

Is it possible to trigger the native iOS login box?
Thanks!

Comment: No, you have no access to the purchaser's identity or Apple ID. You will need your own account system

Comment: Ok thank you, that's what I thought